# NullReferenceException при кешировании объекта в Unity

Tags: unity3d, кэширование

Проект в Unity. Создаю синглтон из префаба с формой настроек, который инициализируется при первом вызове (нажатие на кнопку "настройки"):

```
PrefParCanvas.Instance.ShowOptions();
```

Затем, перед выводом формы (в функции Start, например), происходит вызов функции:

```
public void initFirst()
{
    mainSlider = GameObject.Find("Slider").GetComponent<Slider>();
    if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("complexT"))
        mainSlider.value = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("complexT");
    else
    {
        mainSlider.value = 4;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("complexT", 4);
    }

    if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Music"))
    {

        GameObject.Find("PrefParCanvas/settPanelPar/settPanel/BtnMusic/ico_mus_on").SetActive(PlayerPrefs.GetString("Music") != "no");
        GameObject.Find("PrefParCanvas/settPanelPar/settPanel/BtnMusic/ico_mus_off").SetActive(PlayerPrefs.GetString("Music") == "no");

        GameObject.Find("PrefParCanvas/settPanelPar/settPanel/MusicTxt").GetComponent<Text>().text = (PlayerPrefs.GetString("Music") != "no") ? "Sound on" : "Sound off";
    }
}
```

И на строке

```
mainSlider.value = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("complexT");
```

вылезает ошибка

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
PrefParCanvas.initFirst () (at Assets/Scripts/PrefParCanvas.cs:48)
PrefParCanvas.ShowOptions () (at Assets/Scripts/PrefParCanvas.cs:28)
InterfaceBehaviour.OnMouseUpAsButton () (at Assets/Scripts/InterfaceBehaviour.cs:150)
UnityEngine.SendMouseEvents:DoSendMouseEvents(Int32)
```

Переменная mainSlider объявляется в классе PrefParCanvas:

```
public Slider mainSlider;
```

Если каждый раз искать компонент
            GameObject.Find("PrefParCanvas/settPanelPar/settPanel/Slider").GetComponent().value = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("complexT");

а не кешировать его, как написано выше, то ошибки нет. Как с этим жить? Кеширование пробовал производить в разные моменты после инициализации, результат одинаковый.
В принципе, основной вопрос был как избежать ошибки (решил его, отказавшись от кеширования), но теперь чисто академический интерес - как прикрутить кеширование этого объекта?
Кешируемый объект один из дочерних элементов префаба.

Comment: кэшированием Вы называете `mainSlider` - член класса с методом `initFirst`?

Comment: Ну типа того) Чтобы не выполнять каждый раз поиск элемента, я обычно присваиваю переменной результат поиска и пользуюсь полученной ссылкой на объект. Я не прав? Вычитал подобное обозначение в документации по Unity, если честно.

Comment: `PrefParCanvas.Instance` - точно синглтон?

Comment: Да, готовый класс уже для верности впихнул и унаследовал - в дебаге при попытке создания второго instance выводится в логе ссылка на первый intance и не создаётся новый.

Comment: ну тогда я не понимаю, как в существующем инстансе может обнулиться ссылка, являющаяся членом класса